# System keeps rebooting since last kernel update

Tags: release-hera, updates, pantheon, kernel

In the last few days, I've been having major problems with a system that had been running fine for quite a while (got it on July 1st). The system keeps rebooting every time it is idle, I believe it is when trying to go into sleep mode (which I have tried to disable but I have not succeeded).

One important info is that if I log from the command line (Ctlr-Alt-F2), it will not reboot. I believe this is linked to the GUI. I could no see anything sending a reboot signal in the logs or using systemctl.

You will see below that the behaviour started following the update of the kernel from 5.4.0-42-generic to 5.3.0-62-generic (July 29th, see report below).

Here's some info on the system :

**Computer**
Lenovo ThinkCentre M630e Mini PC, Intel Core i5-8265U Upto 3.9GHz, 16GB RAM, 1TB NVMe SSD,Intel UHD Graphics 630.

**Version**
Kernel      : Linux 5.4.0-42-generic (x86_64)
Version     : #46~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 07:21:24 UTC 2020
C Library       : GNU C Library / (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27
Distribution        : elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera

**Kernel change and reboots**
Fri Jul 31 11:06    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 10:53    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 10:41    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 10:28    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 10:16    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 10:04    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 08:35    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 08:22    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 08:10    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 07:57    5.4.0-42-generic
Fri Jul 31 05:15    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 17:27    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 17:06    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 16:53    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 16:40    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 16:22    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 15:45    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 15:02    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 14:31    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 13:56    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 13:34    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 12:06    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 11:56    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 11:41    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 08:39    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 08:34    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 08:13    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 08:00    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 04:03    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 30 03:35    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 17:51    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 17:39    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 17:09    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 16:55    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 16:43    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 16:30    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 16:18    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 16:06    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 15:53    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 15:41    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 15:28    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 15:16    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 15:04    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 14:51    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 14:39    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 14:26    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 14:14    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 14:02    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 13:49    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 13:37    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 13:24    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 12:40    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 12:27    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 12:15    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 09:25    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 09:23    5.4.0-42-generic
Wed Jul 29 09:21    5.4.0-42-generic
Thu Jul 23 10:37    5.3.0-62-generic
Thu Jul 16 08:52    5.3.0-62-generic
Mon Jul 6 15:43 5.3.0-62-generic
Thu Jul 2 18:27 5.3.0-62-generic
Thu Jul 2 06:17 5.3.0-62-generic
Wed Jul 1 07:28 5.3.0-61-generic
Wed Jul 1 07:24 5.3.0-61-generic
Wed Jul 1 05:00 5.3.0-61-generic

Any suggestions will be more than appreciated, this is driving me nuts.
In the meantime, is there a way to roll back the update?

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: A similar thing, less extreme though, happened to me after the new 5.4. hwe kernel. Sometimes, the second after suspend, my PC starts resuming from it. This goes on until reboot.

Comment: How did you fix it?

Comment: I haven't. It's not an everyday issue for me and I can just easily leave my PC running instead of putting it to suspend. It's far less annoying than your issue. I'm guessing it will be fixed with the next hwe kernel update or you can just keep using the latest 5.3 hwe kernel, still available in your GRUB menu.

Comment: I wish I had thought of that simple solution. Works like a charm. :)
Thanks, I'll use the old kernel until I get a update.

Comment: You can install grub customizer to easily choose which version of kernel should be set as first to boot as default. Also you will be able to add your own wallpaper to Grub start menu and set font colors. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, That's how I handled it for the workaround. But I still wonder how to flag this issue and who to flag it to (which group of developers) in the proper way. I think it would be important. The problem seems to be triggered by pantheon but impacts the kernel.